# Fatal error (bad field count) while configuring Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, dovecot, mail-server

I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin) to configure a mail server using postfix, dovecot and mysql.

While configuring Postfix I have to uncomment the following lines and then restart Postfix with `service postfix restart`. I keep getting the following error when restarting:

```
root@server-1:~# service postfix restart
 * Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
/usr/sbin/postconf: fatal: file /etc/postfix/master.cf: line 23: bad field count
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: cannot execute /usr/sbin/postconf!
   ...fail!
```

Here's what part of `/etc/postfix/master.cf` looks like:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/smtps # <<< line 23
-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

What's going wrong and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 10):

Problem solved by using correct spacing like so:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps # <<< line 23
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: Yes, looks like at least 2 spaces are needed for the indentation. Once space didn't work for me.